# Helium or Selenium wont click button or Link

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, error-handling

i am web scraping a sneakers website called skechers, now when the LOAD MORE link/button appears while scrolling down to load more Products, it clicks the Element but nothing loads.

Here is my CODE:

```
from helium import*
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = start_firefox("https://www.skechers.com/men/shoes/boots/?srule=price-low-to-high&start=0&sz=24")

time.sleep(5)

for x in range(1,5):
    scroll_down(num_pixels=1000)
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        click(Button('LOAD MORE'))
        time.sleep(10)
        
    except:
        continue

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.page_source,"lxml")

kill_browser()
```

Now i have tried click("LOAD MORE") and also click(Link("LOAD MORE")), But none of them seems to work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
from helium import*
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = start_firefox("https://www.skechers.com/men/shoes/boots/?srule=price-low-to-high&start=0&sz=24")

time.sleep(5)

for x in range(1,5):
    scroll_down(num_pixels=1000)
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        button=s.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"Load More")]')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        
    except:
        continue

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.page_source,"lxml")

kill_browser()
```

use xpath , for some reason that method is not working in firefox but works well in chrome

Comment: hi i tired your above code, but it still just clicks it and nothing loads. I tried in both Firefox as well as chrome :(